# AsyncTask and Thread won't run twice in java / android application

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have an android app, written in java which uses **AsyncTask** to download data. The **AsyncTask** is needed to handle the **progress dialog box** which is shown throughout the download.

The actual download is initiated through a separate thread, **downloadAllUpdater**. Whilst I am aware this is not convention, a thread is required as the process of downloading is spread across 7 classes and there was no other way to update the progress bar whilst the download was occurring as I couldn't run the **publishProgress** call from any other class.

My main activity is shown below:

```
private Download downloadAll;

private int totalBlocksLeft;

private boolean downloadComplete;
private boolean downloadFailed;

private PerformTask currentPerformTask;

public void downloadAllClick(View view) //When the download all button is clicked
{
    currentPerformTask = new PerformTask();

    currentPerformTask.execute();
}

private class PerformTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer>
{
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        usingDialog = new ProgressDialog(WifiAudioActivity.this);

        usingDialog.show();
    }

    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voi) 
    {
        downloadAll = new Download();

        downloadComplete = false;   //Assume the download is not complete

        downloadAllUpdater.start(); 

        downloadFailed = false;

        while ((downloadComplete == false) && (downloadFailed == false))   
        {
            blocksDownloaded = downloadAll.getTotalBlocksLeft();

            publishProgress(blocksDownloaded);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) 
    {
        usingDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) 
    {
        usingDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

Thread downloadAllUpdater = new Thread()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        int runRetryCount = 0;

        while ((!(downloadComplete)) && (!(downloadFailed)))
        {
            downloadComplete = download.downloadAudio(totalBlocksLeft);  //Download the audio

            if (!(downloadComplete))
            {
                runRetryCount++;
            }

            if (runRetryCount > Consts.RETRY_TOTAL)
            {
                downloadFailed = true;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The download is initiated with the click of the button, which initiates the **downloadAllClick()** method.

This all works fine the first time the button is pressed.

However, when the button is pressed a second time (after the first time completition), I receive an error and the program force closes.

I am pretty sure the error is because I am running the Thread, **downloadAllUpdater** a second time, because if I have a separate method with just **downloadAllUpdater.start()**, it also crashes with the same error.

Can anyone help? Below is the error log:

```
08-23 11:22:34.954: W/dalvikvm(1485): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400259f8)

08-23 11:22:35.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1485): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5

08-23 11:22:35.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1485): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

08-23 11:22:35.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)

08-23 11:22:35.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)

08-23 11:22:35.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)

08-23 11:22:35.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)

08-23 11:22:35.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)

08-23 11:22:35.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)

08-23 11:22:35.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)

08-23 11:22:35.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)

08-23 11:22:35.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1485): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.

08-23 11:22:35.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1331)

08-23 11:22:35.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at com.que.wifiaudio.WifiAudioActivity$PerformTask.doInBackground(WifiAudioActivity.java:518)

08-23 11:22:35.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at com.que.wifiaudio.WifiAudioActivity$PerformTask.doInBackground(WifiAudioActivity.java:1)

08-23 11:22:35.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)

08-23 11:22:35.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)

08-23 11:22:35.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1485):     ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `start` a Thread twice. You could make `downloadAllUpdater` a Runnable instead:

```
Runnable downloadAllUpdater = new Runnable() { //rest unchanged
```

And replace the code in `doInBackground` with:

```
new Thread(downloadAllUpdater).start();
```

That way, a new thread is created every time, running the same task.

However `doInBackground` is already running on a background thread, are you sure you need to create a new thread? If not, just run the runnable: `downloadAllUpdater.run();` without creating a new thread.

Comment: sorry, neither seem to work. If I try the new Thread(downloadAllUpdater).start();, it gives the same error and the downloadAllUpdater.run() doesn't update the progress bar.

Comment: You should not get the same error if you have made `downloadUpdater` a Runnable and start a new thread each time, maybe a different error? Also, all the variables that you share across threads (`downloadComplete`, `totalBlocksLeft` and `downloadFailed`) should be volatile.

Comment: It's definitely the same error, exactly - evidently it isn't the thread? I'll make the variables volatile, just incase that helps.

Comment: Ok, I can't have updated the code properly. You're right, it now doesn't throw the error the second time round, but the thread doesn't restart.

Comment: Either `start` is called and it does start again or it is not called. You should add some logs in your code to better understand what gets executed and when.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is related to the error you're seeing, but your current code is not thread safe. You're currently assigning the member variables `downloadComplete` and `downloadFailed` from two different threads (`PerformTask` and `downloadAllUpdater`). This usage will lead to race conditions and unexpected results. Please read about the [concurrency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) (namely, the `synchronized` keyword), to synchronize your threads.

Comment: Thanks - I knew about synchronized methods, didn't know about variables

Answer (score 0):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        //do you download here

                    }
                });
```

within Asyctask you cannot access stuff happening in a different theread