# Got IllegalThreadStateException when Invoking HandlerThread.start() second time after HandlerThread.quit()

Tags: android, handler, android-handlerthread

First time ,i invoke HandlerThread.start() to handle the background service. after all the stuffs completed,I wanna to end this Thread by calling HandlerThread.quit().

Then the second time,I start this Handler,and checked the HandlerThread.isAlive(),the isAlive() return false, but when i invoke HandlerThread again by HandlerThread.start().

**But** I got the **IllegalThreadStateException**,*why*?

How can i really stop the HandlerThread before I invoke handlerThread.start() again safely?

```
  onCreate(){
  ...............
  CurrentLocationPresenter = 
       new  CurrentLocationPresenter(getApplicationContext(),mHandler);
    }

  public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id){
        case  R.id.showplacebutton:
            showPlaceInMapActivity();
            break;

        case  R.id.showgpsbutton:     

            if (mCurrentLocationPresenter.isAlive()){
                break;
            }

            mCurrentLocationPresenter.start();
            break;


    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == CurrentLocationPresenter.WHATCODE){

            mCurrentLatlng = (LatLng) msg.obj;
            mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (mCurrentLatlng!=null) {
                mTextView.setText(mCurrentLatlng.toString());
            }
            mCurrentLocationPresenter.getLooper().quit();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated, you can never call the start/run/execute method on a thread object more than once, as you will get the [IllegalThreadStateException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalThreadStateException.html).

You can, however, use something such as an [ExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) which will allow you to use the same [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) multiple times.

Also, if you use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), which is a descendant of ExecutorService, the memory and thread management is taken care of.

Comment: thanks ,i have already know this by read the souce code of google ,because after  this thread.start() ,the thread has been marked,and can not being start again.

Comment: I also don't see why you would want to stop the thread, as the HandlerThread's looper will continue to handle messages until it is told to stop. Unless that is your intention, in which case, I have to ask why are you trying to stop and then restart the looper?

Comment: If you want to stop just the looper (the part where the messages actually get handled) of the thread, then you'd call 

mCurrentLocationPresenter.getLooper().stop();

And to restart the looper

mCurrentLocationPresenter.getLooper().loop();

From what I am understanding, you don't need to restart the thread, you need to restart the looper in the thread.

Comment: Thank you again.The case like this:when  I Click the Button then I start a HandlerThread to send message to the UI Thread,but if I want to Click this    Button again,the app crashed.That's  my case.Now I set the Button unClickable after first time,or every time I clicking the button then new this HandlerThread.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call asyntask.execute() on same object more than one.

Always call MyasynTask asyntask=new MyasynTask();

```
 asyntask.execute();
```

for more [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090251/asynctask-and-thread-wont-run-twice-in-java-android-application)

Comment: First time,I found this phenomenon.But I thought this will create a new object everytime when I Click this button.  Would this  waste too many memory?